# Application data storage architecture

Tags: database, windows, database-design, architecture, data-storage

We have to develop an application for companies that do machine maintenance. Each company has one or more eployees. Data has to be shared between employees and managers (Customers, orders, machine data etc).
The problem is that on site (where the work has to be done, and the software has to do its work) no internet connection is available.

How do we design the data storage architecture? How can data both be available offline, AND shared between different pc's if a network or internet connection is available?

We can use any Microsoft technology for this, except Metro.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow anyway take a look to _Microsoft Sync Framework_.

Comment: "Microsoft Sync Framework" ... That was all I needed! Thanks!

Comment: You welcome! You'll see isn't such easy but it's a solid starting point.